# How to use an Array in a class?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I make that I not have to give the function every time an Array. If I leave it and use the Class Parameter it just dont work :/
Error: Cannot make a static reference to a nonstatic field if I remove the parameter.

```
public class Game {

    public String[][] board = new String[13][13];

    
    public Game() {
        String[][] board = new String[13][13];
    }

    public static void makecross1(String[][] board) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                board[i][j] = " ";
                ;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 3; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 5; j < 8; j++) {
                board[i][j] = "o";
                board[j][i] = "o";
            }
        }
        Random r = new Random();
        while (true) {
            int x = r.nextInt(13);
            int y = r.nextInt(13);
            if (board[x][y].equals("o")) {
                board[x][y] = "/";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `public String[][] feld = new String[13][13];` to `private String[][] board = new String[13][13];` and remove the `board` parameter. Not sure why you thought `feld` and `board` were the same thing.

Comment: oh that was only because I forgot to rename here feld thats all

Comment: `makecross1` is a *`static`* method. If you want to access class members, you need to make it non-`static`. Alternatively you could make `board` `static`, but that’s usually not a good idea for modifiable data.

Comment: how can I do it to a non- Static Method?

Comment: `public void makecross1() {`

Comment: Thank you I am not used to Java so thank you very much :3

Comment: SIDE NOTE: 2D arrays are ROW MAJOR, so at the bottom of your code you should swap the order of the `x` and `y` spots when accessing the array, such as `board[y][x]`. Your current code will work as is, but only because the 2D array is SQUARE. If you had a rectangular array then it'd be a different story...

Comment: Yeah I got that Problem already somewhere else in my code and solved it. But thank you for the reminder.